# How to create an event in google calendar from another Alexa Skill Kit?

Tags: events, alexa-skills-kit

I am building a Alexa Skill Set which returns list of events. I would like to my skill to book an appointment for selected events by the user.

If the user says "Alexa book appointment for the last event", I want my skill to handle it and book an event in the linked calendar.

How do I get access to the linked calendar within my skill?

Answer (score 2):

For this, you need to get access to the user's calendar, which you can get via account linking. You can find more information by Amazon here: [Link an Alexa User with a User in Your System](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/link-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system.html).

In the account linking process, you then need to use [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in). Here's another helpful link for Google Calendar specifically: 
[Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth).

Comment: While the links may answer the question, it is always best to provide the key information from the URL in your answer. This serves two purposes: (i) it saves users the trouble of visiting the external link and searching for what you wanted them to see, and (ii) the information is always available in your answer even if the link stops working. Please edit your answer and include the key information.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that. However, these are very complex processes that required step-by-step guidance based on the use case + interaction with two different APIs that are subject to change. Hence, I added the official links to guide the person the the right address.

Comment: In that case, you should have posted the links in a comment. :)