# Can an Alexa skill add to your calendar?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm just diving into creating an Alexa skill and while the [Event Intents page](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/event-intents.html) says:

> An event happening at a certain time and location, such as a meeting, concert, lecture, or festival. These intents let users make requests related to events, such as **adding an event to a calendar**, or looking up details of an event.

it only ever lists how to read and search the calendar. Is there a way to have an Alexa skill add an event to a calendar?

Comment: The document that you linked to shows the call AMAZON.AddAction<object@Event> for adding events and AMAZON.SearchAction<object@Event> for searching as well as all the other programmable functions that can happen in calendars, all are listed under Event Intents.

Comment: review this SO post for steps to programmically do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231553/how-to-create-an-event-in-google-calendar-from-another-alexa-skill-kit

Comment: Thanks. Either I swapped to an alternate reality or that material on the page is new! I'm kind of excited. Thanks for pointing that out. Also, thanks for the link. I will be checking that out too, seems like pretty much everything I needed.

Comment: It's no problem, the platform changes pretty rapidly, so honestly, it may not have been available when you first tried to do it. Big changes happen all the time.